# How do I stop a coroutine from another script in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, scripting

I want to stop the coroutine "spawn" in the following script by referencing it from another separate script. How should I go about doing that?

```cs
public class spawnerAlt : MonoBehaviour
{
    public IEnumerator Spawn;
    private void Start()
    {
        Spawn = delayedSpawn();
        StartCoroutine(Spawn);
    }

    public IEnumerator delayedSpawn()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            spawn();
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
        }
    }

    void spawn()
    {
        Rigidbody2D clone;
        clone = Instantiate(toSpawn, new Vector2(8.39f,Random.Range(upperBound,lowerBound)), transform.rotation);
        clone.velocity = transform.TransformDirection(Vector2.left * speed);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can change the `true` in the `while(true)` to a class variable and then set that bool from another class. And if you want to make it a little bit prettier, make the variable and make it private. Then add a method that sets it to enabled or disabled.

Comment: There is also a `StopCoroutine` https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StopCoroutine.html

Answer (score 0):

One way to stop coroutine immediately through other scripts is to use `StopCoroutine`. To do this, you must first store your coroutine in a variable.

```cs
public Coroutine spawnCoroutine;

private void Start()
{
    spawnCoroutine = StartCoroutine(delayedSpawn());
}
```

The stop method also works as follows.

```cs
public void StopSpawn() => StopCoroutine(spawnCoroutine);
```

---

In the next step, it is enough to get access to the stop method from another script or the same script itself.

```cs
public void AnotherScriptMethod()
{
    FindObjectOfType<spawnerAlt>().StopSpawn(); // for E.G
}
```